# Custom response for root request int the Spring REST HATEOAS with both RepositoryRestResource-s and regular controllers

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, hateoas, spring-hateoas

Let's say I have two repositories:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "person", path = "person")
public interface PersonRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person, Long> {
    List<Person> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

and

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "person1", path = "person1")
public interface PersonRepository1 extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Person1, Long> {
    List<Person1> findByLastName(@Param("name") String name);
}
```

with one regular controller:

```
@Controller
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    @ResponseBody
    public HttpEntity<Hello> hello(@RequestParam(value = "name", required = false, defaultValue = "World") String name) {
        Hello hello = new Hello(String.format("Hello, %s!", name));
        hello.add(linkTo(methodOn(HelloController.class).hello(name)).withSelfRel());
        return new ResponseEntity<>(hello, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Now, a response for `http://localhost:8080/` is:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "person" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/person{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "person1" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/person1{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    }
  }
}
```

but I want to get something like this:

```
{
  "_links" : {
    "person" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/person{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "person1" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/person1{?page,size,sort}",
      "templated" : true
    },
    "hello" : {
      "href" : "http://localhost:8080/hello?name=World"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

```
@Component
public class HelloResourceProcessor implements ResourceProcessor<RepositoryLinksResource> {

    @Override
    public RepositoryLinksResource process(RepositoryLinksResource resource) {
        resource.add(ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(HelloController.class).withRel("hello"));
        return resource;
    }
}
```

based on

- http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#customizing-sdr.customizing-json-output
- [How to add links to root resource in Spring Data REST?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135756/adding-resources-to-root-in-spring-data-rest)

Answer (score 1):

You need to have a ResourceProcessory for your Person resource registered as a Bean.  see https://stackoverflow.com/a/24660635/442773

Comment: But I don't want to change response for any of `http://localhost:8080/person`, `http://localhost:8080/person1` or `http://localhost:8080/hello` requests. I want to change auto-generated response for `http://localhost:8080/` request.