# How to add additional links to the root resource in Spring Data REST?

Tags: spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

The spring-data-rest module automatically scans for all repositories in an app and lists them like this:

```
{
"_links" : {
    "demoRepository" : {
    "href" : "http://localhost/demoRepository{?page,size,sort}",
    "templated" : true
    }
}
```

However I have some resources that are not backed by a database and don't have repository classes.

How can I add simple resources that have their own controller classes into the above list.
Right now the list does not reflect the whole REST api of my app.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add links to root resource in Spring Data REST?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23135756/how-to-add-links-to-root-resource-in-spring-data-rest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement ResourceProcessor and then add Your custom links to RepositoryLinksResource.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/26118405/4090455